# exsheets: how to use skip-below with custom heading

Tags: spacing, exsheets

I am using `exsheets` for making problem sets and worksheets. I made a custom heading, but now `skip-below` key does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{runin-subtitle}{default}{
    runin=true,
    number-post-code = \PrintQuestionClassT{extension}{\ExtensionSymbol}%print superscript star after a question if extension key has nonempty value.
        \space,
    subtitle-pre-code  = (,
    subtitle-post-code = )\space,
    points-pre-code  = (,
    points-post-code = ),
    join = {
        main[r,vc]number[l,vc](-0.333em,0pt);
        main[r,B]subtitle[l,B](0em,0pt);
    },
    attach = {
        main[l,vc]points[l,vc](\linewidth+\marginparsep,0pt)
    }
}
\SetupExSheets{
    headings=runin-subtitle, %If I comment out my custom heading, skip-below works fine.
    skip-below=4em,
    }

\begin{document}

    \begin{question}
        Is this the first question?
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}
        Was that really the first question?
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}
        How many questions are there?
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}
        What is a question?
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}
        Why is there so little vertical space between all these questions?
    \end{question}


\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

As you can see, `skip-below=4em` is having no effect. If I remove the custom heading, `skip-below` works as expected.

How can I use `skip-below` with my custom heading?

Comment: `skip-below` (and `skip-above`) is disabled with `runin` headings. I guess this can be disputed, though. Using the question's `post-body-hook` or `post-hook` options it should still be possible to add `\par\vspace{4em}` or something…

Comment: @clemens Thanks, that worked! I think it would be great to allow `skip-below` for `running` styles. (Why not?). I'm happy to accept this as an answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skip-below` and `skip-above` are disabled with `runin` headings. (That's just the way it is – probably to be disputed, though. There may be reasons for changing the current behaviour.)

Using the question's `post-body-hook` or `post-hook` options it should still be possible to add `\par\vspace{4em}`:

```
\SetupExSheets{
  headings  = runin-subtitle ,
  post-hook = \par\vspace{4em}
}
```